# verifying my understanding of svn branching

Tags: svn, version-control

It seems to me that branching in SVN is essentially a file layout convention. ie. by convention branches are stored in `project_name/branches/branch_name` but it seems to me that the branch could just as easily be stored in `project_name/branch/branch_name`.

Ultimately, it seems to me that the only reason SVN even uses the word "branches" is that it sounds "cooler" than the word "copies". But in the context of SVN they're really the same thing. This is in contrast to git where branching actually means something it seems to me.

Using the SVN definition of branching, as I understand it, copying file.ext to file2.ext and then modifying file2.ext would make file2.ext a branch of file.ext.

Is this all a correct assessment of branching in svn or am I misunderstanding how it all works?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that branching in SVN is essentially a file layout convention.

Yes. Even more - all "accepted" layouts (more than 1) of Subversion repositories is just convention

> it seems to me that the only reason SVN even uses the word "branches" is that it sounds "cooler" than the word "copies".

No, kid. Subversion uses term "branch", because CVS used "branch", many other ancestors of modern VCS used "branch" to refer to trees with initially common but then later diverged history

> in contrast to git where branching actually means something it seems to me

Git's "branches" are really less branches, than branches in other SCMs - it's just pointer to `<some changeset>`, changing in time, while in others it's permanent metadata of revision

> copying file.ext to file2.ext and then modifying file2.ext would make file2.ext a branch of file.ext

Yes. It's so-called "partial branching" in Subversion, when instead of a full copy of the tree only (any) lower part of it is copied